# Usage of a little and little

Tags: determiners

There is only a little/little tea in the teapot, which one is correct?
I'm confused.
When only is used, do we add or drop the article "a"?

Answer (score 1):

"A little" - small quantity, but enough for its purpose.
"Little" - small quantity, but not enough for its purpose.

I have **a little** free time, so I can help you.

I have **little** free time, so I can't help you.

I drink **a little** alcohol every now and then (just enough to relax).

I drink **little** alcohol (hardly ever and barely enough to have any effect on me).

It's the same with "few/a few" for countable nouns:

I have **a few** friends, not many, but that's enough for me.

I have **few** friends. I wish I had more of them.

Comment: Exactly. And you can prove that the negative is there because _few_ and _little_ trigger [Negative Polarity Items](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) while _a few_ and _a little_ don't: _I have little time for anyone_ is OK, but not *_I have a little time for anyone_. BTW, this is a better answer than the one provided in the ostensible duplicate.