# Are these phrases antonyms?

Tags: phrases, antonyms

- "He showed little sign of hawkish attitude"
- "He showed a little sign of hawkish attitude"

Comment: Hello, Anixx. Does this answer your question? [Usage of a little and little](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510309/usage-of-a-little-and-little). I'd prefer 'We have a little time in which to do this' vs 'We have little time in which to do this'. And 'little', 'a little', may be looked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the phrases in your question do differ in meaning, I wouldn't necessarily say that they're antonymous (having the opposite meaning). The CGEL classifies "little" as *minimizer*, (i.e., there is no sign at all of hawkish attitude) whereas *a little* is a diminisher (i.e., only to a restricted extent, there is a sign of hawkish attitude). It now depends on the logic you apply. Binary logic would make the phrases antonymous: "there is not" *vs* "there is (no matter the amount)". Thinking of amount as a spectrum, I would not call them antonyms, because they're not really opposed. Different, yes, but far more similar than e.g. *little sign of hawkish attitude* and *every* sign of hawkish attitude.
Hope this helps.